# IntelliJ IDEA commit always show updating or performing vcs refresh

Tags: git, intellij-idea

If [Use non-modal commit interface] is selected, the submission window will always display [updating]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVTH3.png)

If [Use non-modal commit interface] is not selected, the submission window will always display [performing vcs refresh]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3kJd.png)

All in all, idea's git is stuck

I tried [Invalidating Caches] and restarting the idea, but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

I guessed it was because GIt was stuck, so I tried killing the process and magically it worked:

[image: git process picture]